# Set-Cookie header not present on request after redirect

Tags: asp.net, http, cookies, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

This is a long shot.
I am working on a solution for passing a user's login credentials to [CEF Sharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/) browser.
We have a WinForms application that allows the user to login, now I have developed a web app that has it's own login page but uses the same database.
We want to intigate the new web app with the existing WinForm with a WebBrowser UserControl.
So we want the WebBrowser UserControl to realize the user is already logged and not have to ask the user to login again.

I have developed a solution where I post the user credentials via [IFrame.LoadRequest](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/55.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IFrame_LoadRequest.htm) to a ASP endpoint which creates the auth Cookie and redirects to the main page, bypassing the login.
However the Cookie is not being persisted between request.

### Edit

This is how I am making the request:

```vb
Module NavigateExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Sub Navigate(ByVal browser As IWebBrowser, ByVal url As String, postData As Dictionary(Of String, Object))
        Dim frame As IFrame = browser.GetMainFrame()
        Dim request As IRequest = frame.CreateRequest()
        request.Url = url
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.InitializePostData()
        Dim element = request.PostData.CreatePostDataElement()
        Dim content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData)
        element.Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)
        request.PostData.AddElement(element)
        Dim headers As NameValueCollection = New NameValueCollection()
        headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
        request.Headers = headers
        frame.LoadRequest(request)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Here are two screenshots of each request, the first returns a redirect with the cookie set, but the cookie is not present in the subsequent request.
I have blanked the domain name but they are the same - I was wondering if Same Origin could be the reason?

[image: Redirect with cookie]

[image: Subsequent request with no cookie]

Could someone help me understand why the cookie is not set?
Perhaps you have experience with CEF Sharp and can understand what I am doing or suggest an alternative?

Thanks :-)

Comment: What does your LoadRequest code look like? Please edit your original question rather than post in comment. If your relying on an auth cookie, what exactly do you need to use the logic page for?

Comment: Thanks for repling@amaitland, I'm not at the office now so I will edit the question later. I have managed to come up with an alternative solution that works and is actually pretty cool :-)

Comment: Took me a little bit to find, see https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16650#p41343 cookies aren't persisted for LoadRequest unless you set https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/e213f3728554e911601d61e19038b1c754b21c56/CefSharp/WebBrowserExtensions.cs#L349

Comment: Thank you - Just a simple flag - Thanks for finding it!!

Answer (score 0):

So as pointed out in the comments, all I needed to do was add a simple flag:

```vb
request.Flags = UrlRequestFlags.AllowStoredCredentials
```

---

However as a needlessly complicated solution, I ended using JavaScript with the [ExecuteScriptAsync function](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_ExecuteScriptAsync_1.htm):

```vb
    Private Sub ChromiumWebBrowser1_LoadingStateChanged(sender As Object, e As LoadingStateChangedEventArgs) Handles ChromiumWebBrowser1.LoadingStateChanged

        ChromiumWebBrowser1.ShowDevTools()
        If ChromiumWebBrowser1.CanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame Then
            Dim postData As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
            postData.Add("SecurityUser", New SecurityUser With
                         {
                         .UserID = 101,
                         .FirstName = "Bob",
                         .UserName = "bob",
                         .CompleteName = "Bob Bob",
                         .Email = "bob@bob.bob"
                         })
            postData.Add("RedirectUrl", "menu")
            Dim content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData)
            ChromiumWebBrowser1.ExecuteScriptAsync("functions.utils.loginEx", content)
        End If

    End Sub
```

And then the function:

```
    export var loginEx = (args: any) => {
        let obj = parseJSON(args);
        Services.loginEx.request = obj;
    }
```

I happen to be using [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor) which complicates things, so I need a `LoginService` that registers a reference of itself:

```cs
        public async Task Check()
        {
            var @ref = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
            js.InvokeVoidAsync("functions.utils.registerLoginEx", @ref);
        }
```

Which I call from `index.razor.cs`:

```cs
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            LoginExService.Check();
        }
```

The invoked function:

```
    export var registerLoginEx = (dotNet: DotNet.DotNetObject) => {
        dotNet.invokeMethodAsync("Login", Services.loginEx.request);
    }
```

And finally the Login in the service:

```cs
        [JSInvokable]
        public async Task Login(SecurityUserRequest request)
        {
            transferService.User = request.SecurityUser;
            await http.LoginEx(request);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.RedirectUrl))
            {
                navigation.NavigateTo(request.RedirectUrl);
            }
        }
```

... I may go back to the original solution.
Anywho I am satisfied.